# Perform function on string separated by new line

Tags: javascript

Is there a simpler way to perform a function on parts of a string separated by `<br>` tags than just looping through it?
For example I have a string called numbers and would like to update the string to a new string.

Note I have some with no `<br>` tags like so:

```js
var numbers = '458135';
```

I would like to convert this:

```js
var numbers = '623478<br>268418<br>84678';
```

To this: (stored as a string)

```html
<a href="https://website.com/EditWork.aspx?ID=623478">623478</a>
<br>
<a href="https://website.com.com/EditWork.aspx?ID=268418">268418</a>
<br>
<a href="https://website.com/EditWork.aspx?ID=84678>84678"></a>
```

Comment: Silly question: is this question actually about Java and not Javascript or Groovy or something? Just asking because you're using single quotes.

Comment: I apologize this is javascript!

Comment: does anyone know how to reopen this question? I think it's not opinion based anymore after the edits

Answer (score 3, accepted):

My solution would be to split, map and join it like this:

```js
const numbers = "123<br>456<br>789";

const links = numbers.split('<br>').map(
    element => '<a href="https://website.com/EditWork.aspx?ID=' + element + '">' + element + '</a>'
).join('<br>');
```

Answer (score 2):

You could use the split method which returns you the values in between 
 as array. Then you can iterate over the array and transform it to the format you require.

```
String[] numbersArray = numbers.split("<br>"); 
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
for(String number : numbersArray) {
  sb.append(String.format("<a  target=\"_blank\" rel=\"noopener noreferrer\" href = \"https://website.com/EditWork.aspx?ID=%s\">%s</a><br/>",number, number));
}
String transformedString = sb.toString();
```

Comment: apologies I meant to put Javascript not Java